# AMQP Golang (amqp package) message producer loses message to send

Tags: go, rabbitmq, amqp

I want to publish few messages from file. There is one message per line. Everything runs almost ok, but strange thing occurs: if line is quite long (dozen of kilobytes), then last message is not published at all. My publish code looks like this (mTLS is needed):

```
func main() {
        flag.Parse()

        cfg := new(tls.Config)
        cfg.RootCAs = x509.NewCertPool()

        caCert, err := os.ReadFile(*caFile)
        failOnError(err, "Unable to read CA bundle")
        cfg.RootCAs.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert)

        cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(*certFile, *keyFile)
        failOnError(err, "Unable to read certificate or key")
        cfg.Certificates = append(cfg.Certificates, cert)

        conn, err := amqp.DialTLS(*url, cfg)
        failOnError(err, "Unable to dial with TLS")
        defer conn.Close()

        ch, err := conn.Channel()
        failOnError(err, "Failed to open a channel")

        messages, err := getMessages()
        failOnError(err, "Unable to get messages from file")
        log.Printf("%d messages to publish", len(messages))

        for i, m := range messages {
                log.Printf("publish message, idx: %d, len: %d", i, len(m))
                err = ch.Publish(
                        *exchange,   // exchange
                        *routingKey, // routing key
                        false,
                        false, // immediate
                        amqp.Publishing{
                                ContentType:  "text/plain",
                                Body:         []byte(m),
                                DeliveryMode: amqp.Persistent,
                        })
                failOnError(err, "Failed to publish a message")

        }
        time.Sleep(0 * time.Millisecond) // special reason explained at bottom
}
```

So, after reading a file, slice "messages" has 4 elements. Now I run a program:

```
$ go run producer-file.go --cert client.cer --key client.key --ca ca-bundle.pem --url amqps://login:password@server:5671/virtualhost --exchange test_exchange --routing-key test_routing_key --file test_03_bundle4.txt
2023/03/21 12:01:02 4 messages to publish
2023/03/21 12:01:02 publish message, idx: 0, len: 169403
2023/03/21 12:01:02 publish message, idx: 1, len: 169148
2023/03/21 12:01:02 publish message, idx: 2, len: 169659
2023/03/21 12:01:02 publish message, idx: 3, len: 86000
```

Everyting looks good so far, but there's only 3 messages on queue:

```
$ go run consumer.go --cert client.cer --key client.key --ca ca-bundle.pem --url amqps://login:password@server:5671/virtualhost -p 10 --queue test_queue
2023/03/21 12:01:02 Received a message, len: 169403
2023/03/21 12:01:02 Received a message, len: 169148
2023/03/21 12:01:02 Received a message, len: 169659
2023/03/21 12:01:02 Current speed: 3 msg/s
```

As you can see, only idx 0, 1 and 2 was published. Idx = 3 was not. I made some "improvement" and after a "range messages" loop I put sleep 20ms:

```
        time.Sleep(20 * time.Millisecond)
```

Publisher:

```
2023/03/21 12:15:11 4 messages to publish
2023/03/21 12:15:11 publish message, idx: 0, len: 169403
2023/03/21 12:15:11 publish message, idx: 1, len: 169148
2023/03/21 12:15:11 publish message, idx: 2, len: 169659
2023/03/21 12:15:11 publish message, idx: 3, len: 86000
```

Consumer:

```
2023/03/21 12:15:15  [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C
2023/03/21 12:15:15 Received a message, len: 169403
2023/03/21 12:15:15 Received a message, len: 169148
2023/03/21 12:15:15 Received a message, len: 169659
2023/03/21 12:15:15 Received a message, len: 86000
2023/03/21 12:15:15 Current speed: 4 msg/s
```

Now there are all messages ready to consume.
I know that publishing is asynchronous, but - in theory - "defer conn.Close()" should protect a publisher code from reset or close connection before all buffers will be empty. Every example on internet is very similar to my producer, so question is: what I did bad that last message is not published at all without this strange time.Sleep()?

Other test show that if msg to publish is quite short (~20 bytes), there is no need to sleep before quit from program - message is small enough to send to RabbitMQ server in time before connection is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Any time messages are published to RabbitMQ you should be using Publisher Confirmations - https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#publisher-confirms

If you don't, you can't be certain that your messages actually made it to the broker and were routed to a queue.

Please see this example which shows how to use confirms:

https://github.com/rabbitmq/amqp091-go/blob/main/_examples/producer/producer.go

Note that **any** network protocol must have some sort of confirmation mechanism for client applications to be certain that the data they send has been received correctly. This isn't strictly a RabbitMQ issue.